# Chrome extension: Port: Could not establish connection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

My manifest:

```
{
    "name":"name",
    "version":"0.1",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "description":"name app",
    "background":{
        "scripts":[
            "scripts/modernizr.min.js", 
            "scripts/background.js"
            ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
        "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
      }
    ],
    "permissions":[
        "contextMenus", 
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
        ],
    "icons":{
        "16":"images/icon_16.png",
        "128":"images/icon_128.png"
    }
}
```

Background.js has a function that is called:

```
    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener( function( info, tab )
        {
... stuff ...
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tab.id, { action: "showLibraryUI", library: library }, function( response ){} );

    } );
```

In content.js I have a function that listens, but it is never called:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function( request, sender, sendResponse )
    {
...stuff...
} );
```

In _generated_background_page.html for the extension I see this:

Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. 
lastError:29
set lastError:29
dispatchOnDisconnect miscellaneous_bindings:259

I couldn't find a solution for manifest > 2.0 in the other posts here on SO.

Comment: Code looks OK. Are you sure that the `chrome.runtime.onMessage` bit of the code is run?

Comment: Everything in background.js is being run fine. In background.js I'm not sure if chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tab.id, { action: "showLibraryUI", library: library } is working, because the listener in content.js is not called.

Comment: @RobW I found the solution :)

Comment: @RobW Also, I saw someone that recommended that you add a listener into the background and send messages with the content script so that you always know that the content is ready before any message passing happens. What do you think about this? I don't think it would work if you message passing is dependent on an event that happens in background.js.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I had a syntax error in my content.js. This resulted in the content.js not running, and the listener not being present.